# Is bookmarklet code always written as href attribute value?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

As shown in below code,

```
<div id="content">
            Here is my <a href="javascript:(function(){ 
                                            _my_script=document.createElement('SCRIPT');_my_script.type='text/javascript';
                                            _my_script.src='file:///D:/Access/bookmark/bmlet.js';
                                            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_my_script);})();">
                                bookmarklet
                        </a>
        </div>
```

---

Is bookmark code always written as a value of `href`attribute of anchor tag?

If yes, Is it not equivalent to writing a JavaScript callback for `onClick` event?

Comment: What do you mean by bookmark, you have an anchor that does freaky script insert to the head ?

Comment: @adeneo He means bookmarklet.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the anchor, an anchor with a `javascript:` URI is mostly similar to having an `onclick` attribute with the same code.

But bookmarklets aren't intended to be followed directly. The user is supposed to right-click on it and save the URI to their bookmarks. This only works if the code is in the `href` attribute.

Comment: With a first look as a beginner, `href` attr value looked like an object literal notation(`javascript:something`).

Comment: Object literals are surrounded by curly braces.

Comment: `href` attributes are URIs, so `javascript:` is the scheme, analogous to `http:` and `mailto:`.

Answer (score 0):

A *bookmarklet* is a `javascript:` scheme URL which is saved in the browser bookmarks so it can be run on whatever page the user is looking at by accessing it from the Bookmarks menu.

In order to store it in the bookmarks, it needs to be attached to a link that a user can right click and pick "Add to Bookmarks" or drag-and-drop onto their bookmarks toolbar.

It wouldn't work in an onclick attribute (or event handler bound with JS) because it is the URL that is saved in a bookmark.

Comment: I could not write `javascript:alert('Hello')` scheme URL  on address bar unlike `http://google.com` scheme URL

Comment: @overexchange — Modern browsers block it from there due to its use in social engineering attacks.

Comment: Any example, that malfunctioned?